# How do I account for a nested fixed effect using lmer?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I have been modelling some data using `lmer` in R with the basic model structure having time interval (`intoffidhrtime`), type of night (`Daysincedisturb`)and the interaction between these 2 as fixed effects and group (`Batch`), the factor product of ID number and group (Batch_Bird_ID), experimental day (`fdfsrtoff`) and the factor product of experimental day and time in the day as random effects (`fdfsrtoff_intoffidhrtimertoff`) (see below). **I have put the dput (and additionally requested data) of my data at the bottom of this question to avoid clutter!!**

```r
countsleepdataoff25WAKEANGLMM <- lmer(unlist(propnssANG)~as.factor(intoffidhrtime)+
       Daysincedisturb+
   as.factor(intoffidhrtime)*Daysincedisturb+ 
    (1|Batch)+(1|Batch_Bird_ID)+(1|fdfsrtoff)+
     (1|fdfsrtoff_intoffidhrtimertoff),
   data=countsleepdataoff25WAKE)
```

On 1 of 3 types of night (`Daysincedisturb`), I apply 1 of 3 treatments/stressors, thus I wanted to include `Stressor` as a fixed effect in the model. A colleague of mine told me that because these stressors only ever occur on 1 of 3 types of a night, this new `Stressor` factor is actually nested within types of night (`Daysincedisturb`) and suggested that I create a new factor product of `Daysincedisturb_Stressor` to account for this in my model.

I then generated this new model (see below), generated some estimated means and also performed some F-tests.

```r
countsleepdataoff25WAKEANGLMM<-lmer(unlist(propnssANG)~as.factor(intoffidhrtime)+
  Daysincedisturb_Stressor+
 as.factor(intoffidhrtime)*Daysincedisturb_Stressor+
(1|Batch)+(1|Batch_Bird_ID)+(1|fdfsrtoff)+
(1|fdfsrtoff_intoffidhrtimertoff),
 data=countsleepdataoff25WAKE)
```

My problem is that my F tests have told me that `Daysincedisturb_Stressor` has a significant effect, but because it is a linked factor product I have no way of confirming which of the 3 stressors is actually causing this. My colleague then suggested I generate a second model with `Stressor` nested within `Daysincedisturb` and to then re-run my calculations.

My problem is twofold: 1) any notation I have found for nesting in `lmer` uses '/' to denote nesting but this is always within random effects which is not the case here, so I am unsure of what notation to sue within the context of my code; 2) I wonder if I would not get the same result if I were to just include time interval, type of night, stressor and the appropriate interactions all as individual fixed effects something like below.

```r
countsleepdataoff25WAKEANGLMM<-lmer(unlist(propnssANG)~as.factor(intoffidhrtime)+
Daysincedisturb+Stressor+
as.factor(intoffidhrtime)*Daysincedisturb*Stressor+
 (1|Batch)+(1|Batch_Bird_ID)+
 (1|fdfsrtoff)+(1|fdfsrtoff_intoffidhrtimertoff),
data=countsleepdataoff25WAKE)
```

The header of data used for the model fit:

```
structure(list(Batch_Bird_ID_fdfsrtoff_intoffidhrtimertoff = structure(c(61L, 
121L, 181L, 241L, 4L, 64L), levels = c("0-2_1_2_722", "0-2_1_2_724", 
"0-2_1_2_737", "0-2_2_2_722", "0-2_2_2_724", "0-2_2_2_737", "0-2_3_2_722", 
"0-2_3_2_724", "0-2_3_2_737", "0-2_36_3_734", "0-2_37_3_734", 
"0-2_38_3_734", "0-2_39_3_734", "0-2_4_2_722", "0-2_4_2_724", 
"0-2_4_2_737", "0-2_40_3_734", "0-2_41_3_734", "0-2_5_2_722", 
"0-2_5_2_724", "0-2_5_2_737", "0-2_6_2_722", "0-2_6_2_724", "0-2_6_2_737", 
"0-2_64_4_725", "0-2_64_4_726", "0-2_64_4_738", "0-2_65_4_725", 
"0-2_65_4_726", "0-2_65_4_738", "0-2_66_4_725", "0-2_66_4_726", 
"0-2_66_4_738", "0-2_67_4_725", "0-2_67_4_726", "0-2_67_4_738", 
"0-2_68_4_725", "0-2_68_4_726", "0-2_68_4_738", "0-2_69_4_725", 
"0-2_69_4_726", "0-2_69_4_738", "0-2_85_5_740", "0-2_85_5_741", 
"0-2_85_5_742", "0-2_86_5_740", "0-2_86_5_741", "0-2_86_5_742", 
"0-2_87_5_740", "0-2_87_5_741", "0-2_87_5_742", "0-2_88_5_740", 
"0-2_88_5_741", "0-2_88_5_742", "0-2_89_5_740", "0-2_89_5_741", 
"0-2_89_5_742", "0-2_90_5_740", "0-2_90_5_741", "0-2_90_5_742", 
"2-4_1_2_722", "2-4_1_2_724", "2-4_1_2_737", "2-4_2_2_722", "2-4_2_2_724", 
"2-4_2_2_737", "2-4_3_2_722", "2-4_3_2_724", "2-4_3_2_737", "2-4_36_3_734", 
"2-4_37_3_734", "2-4_38_3_734", "2-4_39_3_734", "2-4_4_2_722", 
"2-4_4_2_724", "2-4_4_2_737", "2-4_40_3_734", "2-4_41_3_734", 
"2-4_5_2_722", "2-4_5_2_724", "2-4_5_2_737", "2-4_6_2_722", "2-4_6_2_724", 
"2-4_6_2_737", "2-4_64_4_725", "2-4_64_4_726", "2-4_64_4_738", 
"2-4_65_4_725", "2-4_65_4_726", "2-4_65_4_738", "2-4_66_4_725", 
"2-4_66_4_726", "2-4_66_4_738", "2-4_67_4_725", "2-4_67_4_726", 
"2-4_67_4_738", "2-4_68_4_725", "2-4_68_4_726", "2-4_68_4_738", 
"2-4_69_4_725", "2-4_69_4_726", "2-4_69_4_738", "2-4_85_5_740", 
"2-4_85_5_741", "2-4_85_5_742", "2-4_86_5_740", "2-4_86_5_741", 
"2-4_86_5_742", "2-4_87_5_740", "2-4_87_5_741", "2-4_87_5_742", 
"2-4_88_5_740", "2-4_88_5_741", "2-4_88_5_742", "2-4_89_5_740", 
"2-4_89_5_741", "2-4_89_5_742", "2-4_90_5_740", "2-4_90_5_741", 
"2-4_90_5_742", "4-6_1_2_722", "4-6_1_2_724", "4-6_1_2_737", 
"4-6_2_2_722", "4-6_2_2_724", "4-6_2_2_737", "4-6_3_2_722", "4-6_3_2_724", 
"4-6_3_2_737", "4-6_36_3_734", "4-6_37_3_734", "4-6_38_3_734", 
"4-6_39_3_734", "4-6_4_2_722", "4-6_4_2_724", "4-6_4_2_737", 
"4-6_40_3_734", "4-6_41_3_734", "4-6_5_2_722", "4-6_5_2_724", 
"4-6_5_2_737", "4-6_6_2_722", "4-6_6_2_724", "4-6_6_2_737", "4-6_64_4_725", 
"4-6_64_4_726", "4-6_64_4_738", "4-6_65_4_725", "4-6_65_4_726", 
"4-6_65_4_738", "4-6_66_4_725", "4-6_66_4_726", "4-6_66_4_738", 
"4-6_67_4_725", "4-6_67_4_726", "4-6_67_4_738", "4-6_68_4_725", 
"4-6_68_4_726", "4-6_68_4_738", "4-6_69_4_725", "4-6_69_4_726", 
"4-6_69_4_738", "4-6_85_5_740", "4-6_85_5_741", "4-6_85_5_742", 
"4-6_86_5_740", "4-6_86_5_741", "4-6_86_5_742", "4-6_87_5_740", 
"4-6_87_5_741", "4-6_87_5_742", "4-6_88_5_740", "4-6_88_5_741", 
"4-6_88_5_742", "4-6_89_5_740", "4-6_89_5_741", "4-6_89_5_742", 
"4-6_90_5_740", "4-6_90_5_741", "4-6_90_5_742", "6-8_1_2_722", 
"6-8_1_2_724", "6-8_1_2_737", "6-8_2_2_722", "6-8_2_2_724", "6-8_2_2_737", 
"6-8_3_2_722", "6-8_3_2_724", "6-8_3_2_737", "6-8_36_3_734", 
"6-8_37_3_734", "6-8_38_3_734", "6-8_39_3_734", "6-8_4_2_722", 
"6-8_4_2_724", "6-8_4_2_737", "6-8_40_3_734", "6-8_41_3_734", 
"6-8_5_2_722", "6-8_5_2_724", "6-8_5_2_737", "6-8_6_2_722", "6-8_6_2_724", 
"6-8_6_2_737", "6-8_64_4_725", "6-8_64_4_726", "6-8_64_4_738", 
"6-8_65_4_725", "6-8_65_4_726", "6-8_65_4_738", "6-8_66_4_725", 
"6-8_66_4_726", "6-8_66_4_738", "6-8_67_4_725", "6-8_67_4_726", 
"6-8_67_4_738", "6-8_68_4_725", "6-8_68_4_726", "6-8_68_4_738", 
"6-8_69_4_725", "6-8_69_4_726", "6-8_69_4_738", "6-8_85_5_740", 
"6-8_85_5_741", "6-8_85_5_742", "6-8_86_5_740", "6-8_86_5_741", 
"6-8_86_5_742", "6-8_87_5_740", "6-8_87_5_741", "6-8_87_5_742", 
"6-8_88_5_740", "6-8_88_5_741", "6-8_88_5_742", "6-8_89_5_740", 
"6-8_89_5_741", "6-8_89_5_742", "6-8_90_5_740", "6-8_90_5_741", 
"6-8_90_5_742", "8-10_1_2_722", "8-10_1_2_724", "8-10_1_2_737", 
"8-10_2_2_722", "8-10_2_2_724", "8-10_2_2_737", "8-10_3_2_722", 
"8-10_3_2_724", "8-10_3_2_737", "8-10_36_3_734", "8-10_37_3_734", 
"8-10_38_3_734", "8-10_39_3_734", "8-10_4_2_722", "8-10_4_2_724", 
"8-10_4_2_737", "8-10_40_3_734", "8-10_41_3_734", "8-10_5_2_722", 
"8-10_5_2_724", "8-10_5_2_737", "8-10_6_2_722", "8-10_6_2_724", 
"8-10_6_2_737", "8-10_64_4_725", "8-10_64_4_726", "8-10_64_4_738", 
"8-10_65_4_725", "8-10_65_4_726", "8-10_65_4_738", "8-10_66_4_725", 
"8-10_66_4_726", "8-10_66_4_738", "8-10_67_4_725", "8-10_67_4_726", 
"8-10_67_4_738", "8-10_68_4_725", "8-10_68_4_726", "8-10_68_4_738", 
"8-10_69_4_725", "8-10_69_4_726", "8-10_69_4_738", "8-10_85_5_740", 
"8-10_85_5_741", "8-10_85_5_742", "8-10_86_5_740", "8-10_86_5_741", 
"8-10_86_5_742", "8-10_87_5_740", "8-10_87_5_741", "8-10_87_5_742", 
"8-10_88_5_740", "8-10_88_5_741", "8-10_88_5_742", "8-10_89_5_740", 
"8-10_89_5_741", "8-10_89_5_742", "8-10_90_5_740", "8-10_90_5_741", 
"8-10_90_5_742"), class = "factor"), Batch_Bird_ID = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("2_722", "2_724", "2_737", "3_734", 
"4_725", "4_726", "4_738", "5_740", "5_741", "5_742"), class = "factor"), 
    Batch = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("2", 
    "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Bird_ID = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("722", "724", "725", "726", 
    "734", "737", "738", "740", "741", "742"), class = "factor"), 
    fdfsrtoff_intoffidhrtimertoff = structure(c(25L, 49L, 73L, 
    97L, 2L, 26L), levels = c("0-2_1", "0-2_2", "0-2_3", "0-2_36", 
    "0-2_37", "0-2_38", "0-2_39", "0-2_4", "0-2_40", "0-2_41", 
    "0-2_5", "0-2_6", "0-2_64", "0-2_65", "0-2_66", "0-2_67", 
    "0-2_68", "0-2_69", "0-2_85", "0-2_86", "0-2_87", "0-2_88", 
    "0-2_89", "0-2_90", "2-4_1", "2-4_2", "2-4_3", "2-4_36", 
    "2-4_37", "2-4_38", "2-4_39", "2-4_4", "2-4_40", "2-4_41", 
    "2-4_5", "2-4_6", "2-4_64", "2-4_65", "2-4_66", "2-4_67", 
    "2-4_68", "2-4_69", "2-4_85", "2-4_86", "2-4_87", "2-4_88", 
    "2-4_89", "2-4_90", "4-6_1", "4-6_2", "4-6_3", "4-6_36", 
    "4-6_37", "4-6_38", "4-6_39", "4-6_4", "4-6_40", "4-6_41", 
    "4-6_5", "4-6_6", "4-6_64", "4-6_65", "4-6_66", "4-6_67", 
    "4-6_68", "4-6_69", "4-6_85", "4-6_86", "4-6_87", "4-6_88", 
    "4-6_89", "4-6_90", "6-8_1", "6-8_2", "6-8_3", "6-8_36", 
    "6-8_37", "6-8_38", "6-8_39", "6-8_4", "6-8_40", "6-8_41", 
    "6-8_5", "6-8_6", "6-8_64", "6-8_65", "6-8_66", "6-8_67", 
    "6-8_68", "6-8_69", "6-8_85", "6-8_86", "6-8_87", "6-8_88", 
    "6-8_89", "6-8_90", "8-10_1", "8-10_2", "8-10_3", "8-10_36", 
    "8-10_37", "8-10_38", "8-10_39", "8-10_4", "8-10_40", "8-10_41", 
    "8-10_5", "8-10_6", "8-10_64", "8-10_65", "8-10_66", "8-10_67", 
    "8-10_68", "8-10_69", "8-10_85", "8-10_86", "8-10_87", "8-10_88", 
    "8-10_89", "8-10_90"), class = "factor"), fdfsrtoff = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "64", "65", "66", 
    "67", "68", "69", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90"), class = "factor"), 
    intoffidhrtimertoff = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("0-2", 
    "2-4", "4-6", "6-8", "8-10"), class = "factor"), intoffidhrtime = structure(c(3L, 
    4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("1-3", "19-21", "21-23", 
    "23-1", "3-5"), class = "factor"), mindfsprtimertoff = c(1.083333333, 
    1.166666667, 1.25, 1.333333333, 2, 2.083333333), maxdfsprtimertoff = c(1.165972222, 
    1.249305556, 1.332638889, 1.415972222, 2.082638889, 2.165972222
    ), mindfsprtime = c(0.875, 0.958333333, 1.041666667, 1.125, 
    1.791666667, 1.875), maxdfsprtime = c(0.957638889, 1.040972222, 
    1.124305556, 1.207638889, 1.874305556, 1.957638889), Daysincedisturb = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Disturbed", "Recovery", 
    "UnDisturbed"), class = "factor"), Stressor = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("FeedDeprivation", "FootPain", 
    "None", "Temperature"), class = "factor"), Disturbance = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    localDisturbance = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), Sleep_State = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("WAKE", "SWS", "REM", "REST"
    ), class = "factor"), artefcount = c(11L, 10L, 15L, 19L, 
    10L, 11L), totcountinclartef = c(120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 
    120L, 120L), artefpropn = c(0.091666667, 0.083333333, 0.125, 
    0.158333333, 0.083333333, 0.091666667), countss = c(30L, 
    50L, 33L, 37L, 62L, 56L), totcountexclartef = c(109L, 110L, 
    105L, 101L, 110L, 109L), propnss = c(0.275229358, 0.454545455, 
    0.314285714, 0.366336634, 0.563636364, 0.513761468), missingcount = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), missingpropn = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), totalmissingpropn = c(0.0916666666666667, 
    0.0833333333333333, 0.125, 0.158333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 
    0.0916666666666667), Daysincedisturb_Stressor = structure(c(5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("Disturbed_FeedDeprivation", 
    "Disturbed_FootPain", "Disturbed_Temperature", "Recovery_None", 
    "UnDisturbed_None"), class = "factor"), propnssANG = c(31.6428714912652, 
    42.3920457409248, 34.0981259876772, 37.2473732223974, 48.6560109841391, 
    45.7885736166779)), row.names = c(8L, 12L, 16L, 20L, 24L, 
28L), class = "data.frame")

structure(c(44L, 0L, 0L, 44L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 101L, 19L, 49L, 0L, 
0L), dim = 3:4, dimnames = list(Daysincedisturb = c("Disturbed", 
"Recovery", "UnDisturbed"), Stressor = c("FeedDeprivation", "FootPain", 
"None", "Temperature")), class = "table")
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the results of  `with(dcountsleepdataoff25WAKE, table(Daysincedisturb, Stressor))` ? I can't quite tell from the subset of data you've given or your verbal description ...

Comment: @BenBolker I have added the output above as per your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** I think getting everything you want from this slightly odd experimental design is tricky. I think the *easiest* solution would  be to fit two separate models, (1) with `Daysincedisturb` only (and not `Stressor`) as a predictor, and (2) using `Stressor` as a predictor, but including only data from the "Disturbed" category.  There would be a slight loss of power (since you would have a little bit less data in the second model to estimate the other effects in the model).

For the rest, I'll try to explain what's going on and why this is tricky.

I'm going to ignore everything but the `Daysincedisturb` × `Stressor` interaction, as that's the difficult bit. We don't even have to mess around with mixed models, all of the difficulty fits into the linear model (`lm()`) framework.

Starting with the table representing the experimental design:

```r
tab <- structure(c(44L, 0L, 0L, 44L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 101L, 19L, 49L, 0L, 
0L), dim = 3:4, dimnames = list(Daysincedisturb = c("Disturbed", 
"Recovery", "UnDisturbed"), Stressor = c("FeedDeprivation", "FootPain", 
"None", "Temperature")), class = "table")

              Stressor
Daysincedisturb FeedDeprivation FootPain None Temperature
    Disturbed                44       44    0          49
    Recovery                  0        0  101           0
    UnDisturbed               0        0   19           0
```

Now I'm going to reconstruct a simulated example that looks like your data to play with:

```r
tdf <- as.data.frame(tab)
dd <- with(tdf, data.frame(Daysincedisturb = rep(Daysincedisturb, Freq),
                           Stressor = rep(Stressor, Freq)))
stopifnot(nrow(dd) == sum(tdf$Freq))
with(dd, table(Daysincedisturb, Stressor))

beta <- 0:12
X <- model.matrix(~Daysincedisturb:Stressor, dd)
set.seed(101)
dd$y <- rnorm(nrow(dd), mean = X %*% beta, sd = 0.01)
```

I'm going to use the `faux` package because it generates parameter names that are a little more explicit/easy to interpret.

```r
library(faux)
dd <- transform(dd,
                Daysincedisturb = contr_code_sum(Daysincedisturb),
                Stressor = contr_code_sum(Stressor))
m1 <- lm(y ~ Daysincedisturb/Stressor, dd)
c(na.omit(coef(m1)))
print(na.omit(coef(summary(m1))), digits = 3)
```

(t- and p-values omitted for brevity)

```r
                                                            Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)                                                    7.334   0.000830
Daysincedisturb.Disturbed-intercept                           -2.334   0.000951
Daysincedisturb.Recovery-intercept                             0.666   0.000990
DaysincedisturbDisturbed:Stressor.FeedDeprivation-intercept   -4.001   0.001149
DaysincedisturbDisturbed:Stressor.FootPain-intercept          -1.000   0.001149
```

It looks like R has dropped/set to NA a sensible subset of parameters in this case; however what we get are *not* the contrasts we want, since everything is compared to the overall intercept (the average of all stressors and days).

I also tried this, which I think *does* get what you want: use treatment contrasts for `Daysincedisturb` and sum-to-zero contrasts for `Stressor`, and fit an **additive** model.

```r
dd <- transform(dd,
   Daysincedisturb = contr_code_treatment(Daysincedisturb),
   Stressor = contr_code_sum(Stressor))
m2 <- lm(y ~ Daysincedisturb + Stressor, dd)
```

```
                                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                                  5   0.000806    6206        0
Daysincedisturb.Recovery-Disturbed           3   0.001236    2428        0
Daysincedisturb.UnDisturbed-Disturbed        4   0.002306    1736        0
Stressor.FeedDeprivation-intercept          -4   0.001149   -3481        0
Stressor.FootPain-intercept                 -1   0.001149    -870        0
```

This gives us contrasts between the Disturbed day and the other days, and contrasts between the stressors and the intercept in the baseline level of `Daysincedisturb`, which is "Disturbed". I think that with this model, using pairwise contrasts etc. with the `emmeans` package will do what you want ...